# Collapsing Toolbar layout setTitle doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to do a nestedScrollview with collapsing toolbar but when I call in my activity collapsingToolbar.setTitle("my title") it doesn't work.
Here is my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/coll_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:id="@+id/view_toolbar">

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha" android:id="@+id/image_btn"
                                 android:background="#00ffffff" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                 android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/textee"
                      android:text="svsdvsdvbshvdfcbsdvbsvbshdbvsdvsdhvbsdhvbsdhvbsdhvbsdhvbsdhbvsdhvbsdhvbsdhbvsdhvbsdhbvsdhbvsdhbvsdhdbvshdbvshdbvshbvsdhbvsdhbvsdhvbsdhvbsdhvbsdhvbsdhvb"
                      android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="34dp"
                      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here I call setTitle

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view__activity);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.coll_toolbar);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.view_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collToolbar.setTitle("Caccaaa!!");
```

[image]

And how do I change the color of the arrow and the scissors?
I tried using `<item name="titleTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>` in my theme but it doesn't work
Thanks!

Comment: there was a bug in previous Design Support Library version, update to latest version first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what is happenning, is that your  is showing up when your toolbar is collapsing...

Remove this code for starters (then maybe refactor differently for your needs):

```
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha" android:id="@+id/image_btn"
                         android:background="#00ffffff" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                         android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It definitely works! But how can I add an ImageButton in my collapseLayout. And how do I chenge the title color? Thanks!

Comment: There are APIs for the other things you want to do, but that is a different question ;-).  Glad this worked!

Comment: Can you point me out something about button in the collapsingview?

Answer (score 2):

hi can you try with this

Instead of:

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout collToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.coll_toolbar);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.view_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
collToolbar.setTitle("Caccaaa!!");
```

Use this

CollapsingToolbarLayout collToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.coll_toolbar);

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.view_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Caccaaa!!");
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This will only set it when the Toolbar is showing, and not when it is expanded FWIW.

Comment: Cacaaa means poop in arabic... +1 for that